# MYSQL table for related records in another table

Tags: mysql

What is the *best* way to have a table to maintain related records of another table.

Example:

```
mytbl
-----
id   sku

1    sk1
2    sk2
3    sk3
4    sk4
5    sk5
6    sk6
7    sk7
```

Lets say records 1, 4 and 3 are 'related'
So I want to maintain a table that tells me that they are.

```
relatedTbl
----------
sku   related_sku

sk1  sk3
sk1  sk4
sk3  sk4
```

This solution would work but, is there a better solution?

*EDIT: I used skus in the relatedTbl but I know I could (better) to use ids. The question is about the structure of the table more than what foreign key to use.*

Comment: N->M relation table. With the mytbl->ID plus mytbl-IDRelated this if the relationship is not hierarchical if it is you have to add on the mytbl-IDParent (no need for new table)

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Not if a record could be related to more than one other record.

Comment: yes a record can be related to many other records. It is not N->M relationship

Comment: @user1032531 I agree with you. But it was just a hint, maybe the multiple related could be a tree like structure.

Comment: It is a N->M not an Hierarchical.

Comment: @user1032531 it is not hierarchical.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, you could be right.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct solution.  As you indicated, use the ID.  If sku is unique, consider using it as a natural PK.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytbl` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relatedTbl` (
  `mytbl_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `mytbl_id1` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mytbl_id`, `mytbl_id1`),
  INDEX `fk_mytbl_has_mytbl_mytbl1_idx` (`mytbl_id1` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_mytbl_has_mytbl_mytbl_idx` (`mytbl_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mytbl_has_mytbl_mytbl`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mytbl_id`)
    REFERENCES `mytbl` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mytbl_has_mytbl_mytbl1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mytbl_id1`)
    REFERENCES `mytbl` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: My solution (and yours) can be the *best* if there is a way to prevent duplicates (using mysql schema)

Comment: For example, sk1 and sk3 relationship should not be added twice by reversing the order
sk3 sk1

Comment: @SamBattat  The schema I proposed will prevent duplicates in one direction due to the composite PK.  Enforcing the reverse will be a  little more complicated.  Maybe considered a trigger?  Or don't worry about it, and when querying the DB, filter as necessary?

Comment: I'm going with triggers for the the other direction uniqueness. I just thought there would be another way out there. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider adding a third field to 'mytbl' in to store a unique key for common records. for instance, field 3 would be named "uniqID", and records 1, 4 and 3 are 'related' the table would then be:

mytbl

id  sku   uniqID

1   sk1    1

2   sk2

3   sk3    1

4   sk4    1

5   sk5

6   sk6

7   sk7

you can then use a 'WHERE uniqID=1' clause at the end of your select statement  to get the common attributes

Comment: This is a poor design as the OP need more than one skus related to others. Your solution does not cover this option.

Comment: yes, as @JorgeCampos pointed out you are suggesting something irrelevant.